# Fetch location of MySQL slow query log via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I discover the filesystem location of the slow query log from php? I'd like to do this dynamically through a query (if possible, or some other runtime method) as opposed to parsing any my.ini files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run this query:

```
show variables like '%slow%';
```